# Error parsing data org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 0

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have been looking over my code all day and can not find why this is happening (or why its not actually returning the result form the MySQL server it should.
Hopefully a fresh pair of eyes will find the reason.

The Jsonparser class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

The inner class within my activity

```
class GetUserDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LogIn.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading User details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", EMAIL));
                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", PASSWORD));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject jsonuser = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_user_detials, "GET", param);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("User Details", jsonuser.toString());

                        // json success tag
                    try {
                        int success = jsonuser.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = jsonuser
                                    .getJSONArray("product"); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                            editor.putInt("USERID", (Integer) product.get("ProfileID")); 
                            editor.commit();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this, MyLists.class);
                            LogIn.this.startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And finally the PHP script on the server talking with the database

```
    <?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET['email'] && isset($_GET['password')) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles_profiles WHERE ProfileEmail = '$email' AND ProfilePassword = '$password'");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["ProfileID"] = $result["ProfileID"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No user found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

and the stack trace for the actual error that I am getting

```
08-18 18:43:55.573: E/JSON Parser(16008): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-18 18:43:55.573: W/dalvikvm(16008): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41515450)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at com.test.app.LogIn$GetUserDetails.doInBackground(LogIn.java:149)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at com.test.app.LogIn$GetUserDetails.doInBackground(LogIn.java:1)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-18 18:43:55.584: E/AndroidRuntime(16008):    ... 5 more
```

and error from PHP

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in /home/sites/pmclient.co.uk/public_html/dadgapp/get_user_details.php on line 19
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Hints: if only `POST` and `GET` make sense, then you shouldn't keep going if you get something else. Don't swallow exceptions - it really doesn't help; it just defers an error.

Comment: May be UTF-8 error? with BOM or near somethink with issue.

Comment: @trololo forgot to say the POST method works fine, only when I do the above GET does it error out

Comment: What do your *PHP server's* logs say?

Comment: @Amber currently do not have access to the PHP server logs but shall try to get access now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot ";" in:

```
$password = $_GET['password']
```

line in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks however after making the change I do still get the error, going to try and get another log

Comment: had a few more syntax errors but solved in the end thanks guys

Comment: yes although I will need to make my app far more robust as it will crash if the user can not be found, but at least it does now work for users that are there